# Symmetry in using structures for conversion. What is best practice?

Tags: swift, structure

I've been playing with Swift and I encoded an obvious conversion structure:

```
struct MutableAngle {
    var degrees : CGFloat
    var radians : CGFloat {
        return degrees * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180.0
    }

    init(inRadians : CGFloat) {
        degrees = inRadians * 180.0 / CGFloat(M_PI)
    }
    init(inDegrees : CGFloat) {
        degrees = inDegrees
    }
}
```

Now this is fine but inelegant since it doesn't treat degrees and radians symmetrically although it does give mutability.  This is really a structure which should be called Degrees and which can provide radians.  For instance, I can write:

```
var angle : MutableAngle
angle.degrees = 45.0
```

but not

```
var angle : MutableAngle
angle.radians = 0.75
```

Here's a final version:

```
struct Angle {
  let degrees : CGFloat
  let radians : CGFloat

  init(inRadians : CGFloat ) {
    radians = inRadians
    degrees = radians * CGFloat (180 / M_PI)
  }
  init(inDegrees : Float ) {
    degrees = inDegrees
    radians = degrees * CGFloat (M_PI / 180)
  }
}
```

Use as follows:

```
var alpha = Angle(inDegrees: 45)
alpha.degrees // returns 45
alpha.radians // returns 0.7853982

// alpha.radians = 0.9  ... is now illegal with let constants
// must use constructor ... provided alpha was defined using 'var'
// i.e. the struct itself is mutable
alpha = Angle(inRadians: 0.9)
alpha.radians // returns 0.7853982
alpha.degrees // returns 45
```

Switching from var to let makes it mutable/immutable depending on how alpha is defined and I'm now obliged to use the constructors which is good. So its symmetric.  It also has the merit that a calculation is not required every time I want to use the radians.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things here:

1. In Swift you don't need a separate mutable type for value types - that's handled by whoever is instantiating the type by using `let` or `var`.
2. Your `radians` computed property only has a getter - you can do what you want with both a setter and a getter.

My implementation:

```
struct Angle {
    var degrees : CGFloat = 0
    var radians : CGFloat {
        get {
            return degrees * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180.0
        }
        set {
            degrees = newValue * 180.0 / CGFloat(M_PI)
        }
    }

    init(inRadians : CGFloat) {
        radians = inRadians
    }
    init(inDegrees : CGFloat) {
        degrees = inDegrees
    }
}
```

Useage:

```
// immutable
let angle = Angle(inDegrees: 180)
println(angle.radians)
// next line gives an error: can't assign to an immutable instance
angle.radians = angle.radians * 2

// mutable copy
var mutableAngle = angle
mutableAngle.degrees = 10
println(mutableAngle.radians)
// 0.1745...
mutableAngle.radians = CGFloat(M_PI)
println(mutableAngle.degrees)
// 180.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nate.  I can't believe I missed the setter.  It solves the symmetry issue perfectly and makes it clear that 'let' is not appropriate as it reintroduces asymmetry.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to use `enum` with associated value:

```
enum MutableAngle {
    case Radian(CGFloat)
    case Degree(CGFloat)

    init(radians:CGFloat) {
        self = .Radian(radians)
    }
    init(degrees:CGFloat) {
        self = .Degree(degrees)
    }

    var radians:CGFloat {
        get {
            switch self {
            case .Radian(let val): return val
            case .Degree(let val): return val * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180.0
            }
        }
        set {
            self = .Radian(newValue)
        }
    }
    var degrees:CGFloat {
        get {
            switch self {
            case .Degree(let val): return val
            case .Radian(let val): return val * 180.0 / CGFloat(M_PI)
            }
        }
        set {
            self = .Degree(newValue)
        }
    }
}

var angle = MutableAngle(radians: 1)
angle.degrees // -> 57.2957795130823
angle.degrees = 180
angle.radians // -> 3.14159265358979
```

Comment: Thank you rintaro, your solution intrigues me but I'm not sure I understand it.  I would never have been able to write that.  Here's what I think you did: an instance is either radians or degrees but capable of returning the other with a getter.  It's not symmetric but its much harder to tell that it's not.  Am I right?